# Why is acceleration in the rotating system zero?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, acceleration, rotational-kinematics, coriolis-effect

Given a circular body that rotates around itself and there is a band(or iron line) that connects between the Cartesian coordinate system and its Perimeter, on the band, there is an ant that walking toward the Perimeter of the circular body with a velocity of $V_R$. why the acceleration ($a_{rot} = 0$)  in the Rotating system? where does the Coriolis force has gone? I am using the formula :

$\vec{a_{rot}}=a_I - \vec{w} \times (\vec{w}\ \times \ \vec{R_{rot}}) - 2\vec{w} \ \times \ \vec{v_{rot}}$
[image]

Comment: What is $a_I$? What is $R_{rot}$? What is $v_{rot}$? Why $V_R$ does not appear in the equation? What is $a_{rot}$ and why do you think it is zero, or why do you oppose it being zero?

Answer (score 0):

The rotatory acceleration $a_{rot}$ is zero whenever the angular velocity $\omega$ is constant in time. Keep in mind that rotatory acceleration is different from the usual acceleration. In particular, we say that in a uniform rotating system, one body rotating with constant $\omega$ constrained on a circumference, there always is a *centrifugal acceleration* $a_c = \omega^2 r$, where r is the radius of the circumference.

I hope I didn't misunderstand what you asked, if I wasn't enough clear or you didn't get the answer you wanted, fell free to ask.